# Use cruisecontrol just to copy code in folders, AFTER build

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net

We have an ASP.NET application, on .NET 2.5, VS2008 and TFS 2010.
We use TFS for builds and the builds get dropped to a build folder.

After a Build happens, we need to manually copy the code from the drop folder to a shared folder on our DEV/AT server for deployment. Some other files need to be manually copied before actual deployed code starts working. E.g. some dlls need to be added, correct environment specific web.config to be dropped, taking backup of last deployed code etc.

Can I use CruiseControl.NET to take care of all the manual copying steps only? So that I still trigger my builds from TFS, but then manually go to CC and trigger a deployment, which would copy code for the final deployment?

If yes, any reference configurations for me to start off with?

Or am I using too complex a tool for this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the deployment from the same TFS Build that builds your code.  I you don't want to deploy every build, but want deployment to be a manual choice, what I typically do is have my TFS Build create powershell scripts and/or batch files into the drop folder, so that if somebody wants to deploy a specific build all they do is run a batch file from the drop location.